# If the sim is out and the phone has been factory reseted can I track it?

Tags: lost-phone

My phone was stolen and I called but they obvioulsy had taken out the sim.They've logged out all my google accounts,twitter,facebook,viber and I'm thinking that 
they did a factory reset!Is there anyway I can track my phone?It was a sony xperia m

Answer (score 1):

With a factory reset, there isn't much you can do. Here are some options that may be useful.

### Tracking apps

If you had the foresight to install some tracking type apps and move it to the system partition via root, those can survive a factory reset (though the preferences may be reset).

### Report as stolen

If you know the IMEI, you can at least report it as stolen. The cell companies can block that phone from their network (both CDMA (non-sim) and GSM (sim) networks can do this; CDMA networks call it ESN instead of IMEI). However, I highly doubt they will help you locate it, even if they could track it.

You can find the IMEI if you kept the original packaging; usually it's on the box or on a sticker in the manuals. Again, you need the foresight to either copy the IMEI or keep the original packing materials.

### Google location history

If you enabled Google Location tracking, you can [view a map](https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/b/0) of the location history for the device. If the thief didn't wipe the device right away, this could give you some clues as to their whereabouts.

If you really want to track it down, you could use that location information and see if there are any security cameras in the area (ask the shops to see if you can view their security tapes). If anything turns up, give the information **to the police**, and don't try any heroics.

Comment: I don't have an IMEI and how can they track it?Why won't they help me?

Comment: The cell companies always know the general location of devices, because they need to know which tower to send a signal out when your cell gets an incoming call. (They don't just blast every tower in the country until your phone accepts). With triangulation, they could theoretically get a rough location of the device.

Comment: Did you ever get your phone serviced? Did you order it online? You may have a receipt or other place where the IMEI was recorded, if you don't still have the original box.

Answer (score 0):

If the phone has been factory reset them no.

Unless you had installed an anti theft app that survives or prevents factory resets I think you're stuck.

Comment: Damn it no I haven't done anything like that!!So there's no hope huh?

Comment: All you can do is have the IMEI number blocked, that way the thief wont be able to use or sell it, but your chances of getting it back are slim.

Comment: And what (slim)chances are these?Because I don't even have the IMEI

Comment: Yeah, you're stuck.

Comment: Greaaat,Damn it

Answer (score 0):

i hope you Android Device Manager app or log into site will give u past location of your phone before the factory reset only. this app is owned by the google and now it auto installed on new phones.